# Unable to find security.dll library on class library application

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl, class-library

I trying to use ssl connection on class library application but i tried to authenticate
as a client to server i got following error message.

"Unable to find an entry point named 'EnumerateSecurityPackagesW' in DLL 'security.dll'."

Have any body experience about this?

Answer (score 1):

Security.dll is also the same name for the Windows DLL containing the SSPI implementation, which is used for authentication. When loading DLLs, the local bin directory will be checked before the Windows directory. As a result, your System.dll is being loaded instead of the SSPI System.dll.

So if in certain situations your custom Security.dll is loaded before 
c:\winnt\system32\security.dll then LoadLibrary thinks it has the dll 
already loaded (since it's just a Win32 Dll, only name matter, NOT version 
information). But as we know this is not the correct dll and hence the 
problem.

The workaround is to change the dll name.